# Datagridview column index changing when binding to a datatable

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, datagridview

i have two datragridviewcomboboxcolumn,and two textbox column in a datagridview.each combobox column is binded to separate binding source.

**column names are sl_no,col_empname,col_empworktype,Col_Hours** etc.and 
displaymember,datapropertyname,valuemember and for comboxcolumn are

col_empname:-emp_name,emp_id,emp_id

col_empworktype:-worktypename,worktypeid,worktypeid

my issues are

1. when i bind data to gridview it shows a extra column emp_id(image 1)
2. when i select the combobox column its column index is changed
3. after selecting the combox column it shows an error datagridview
           '**Datagridviewcombobox values is not valid!'**

[image]

in my form load i have specified datapropertyname

```
Dim employeecolumn As DataGridViewComboBoxColumn = CType(grdWorkStatus.Columns("Col_EmpName"), DataGridViewComboBoxColumn) 
employeecolumn.DisplayMember = "emp_name" 
employeecolumn.ValueMember = "emp_Id" 
employeecolumn.DataPropertyName = "emp_Id" 
employeecolumn.DataSource = EmployeeSource
```

all this issue occur only when i bind data from database to grdiview(Updating grdiview data). Otherwise i am able to save.and evrything is working fine.

[image]

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

When you bind the data table into a `DataGridView`, it will bind all columns from the data table, so if you have emp_id in your data table, then it will be shown on the `DataGridView`.

You may need to create a `emp_id` columns in your dataGridView, use `DataPropertyName` to the columns to `emp_id`, then make the id column invisible.

Comment: Nick.emp_id is the dataproperty name of col_empname.

Comment: Then did you create a column for `col_empname` and make it invisible?

Comment: Dim employeecolumn As DataGridViewComboBoxColumn = CType(grdWorkStatus.Columns("Col_EmpName"), DataGridViewComboBoxColumn)
        employeecolumn.DisplayMember = "emp_name"
        employeecolumn.ValueMember = "emp_Id"
        employeecolumn.DataPropertyName = "emp_Id"
        employeecolumn.DataSource = EmployeeSource

Comment: This i added in my form load.

Comment: @Shyams Is your last comment confirmation that Nick has helped solve your problem? Then please upvote him and mark his as the answer or post a new answer where you explain the full solution. If your comment is instead new information and the issue still exists please put the code in your question and add the new information about the issue.